# Error: is not a valid virtual path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, virtual, path

I used something like
 Dim i As String
            i = Server.MapPath("~/photos/") + fileName
Only once in a project that was working and online, on the offline version, when I run it on my machine, its working, no errors, I uploaded it, it gave me an error like:

> '~/photos/http://www.**MyURL**.com/photos/4411568359267Pic003.jpg' is not a valid virtual path.

Indicating a line in my code:

```
 var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(<%=coordinates%>));
```

This have never happened before, and I don't know where to start troubleshooting as this script -Google Maps- doesn't even need images, i tried to comment it out, it gave me the same error but on a different script this time, the one that show formatting toolbar for the text areas

```
Line 8:  new nicEditor({buttonList : ['fontSize','fontFamily','fontFormat','bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','forecolor','bgcolor','removeformat'], iconsPath : '../nicEdit/nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('<%= txtDescription.ClientID %>');
```

..please HELP :'(

Comment: You sure that's your code? Cut and paste the actual lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, turns out the error is due to old database records when i was storing the whole path in the fileName...Thanks Joshua and Keltex

Answer (score 0):

can you post your fileupload aspx page and your function so we can troubleshoot it.
"'~/photos/http://www.MyURL.com/photos/4411568359267Pic003.jpg'"
look closely at the url, it is tacking the full url on to "i".  what type of control or you using, a generic or a server side control